# Pub/Sub between PHP server and React client using FCM

Tags: php, reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to set up a messaging system between my PHP server and React front end. I managed to publish messages from the PHP server as can be seen in the Metrics:
[image: FCM API metrics showing API requests from PHP server]

The issue I am facing is that I can not receive the messages from React, as per the documentation for the client SDK, there are functions for messaging. But the same page also mentions that I need to use the admin SDK instead??

As for the admin SDK I can not use it since it requires me to upgrade React in my project which can lead to issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered implementing WebSockets between your PHP server and React front end? This would allow for real-time bi-directional communication between the two, without requiring any upgrades to React or the use of the admin SDK. You can use libraries like Socket.io for the server-side implementation and the WebSocket API for the client-side implementation. This approach can provide a fast and efficient way to send and receive messages.